# What is the browser engine used by HTML5/Javascript Universal Apps in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app

In Windows 10, it is possible to create Universal Apps using HTML5 and Javascript (as an alternative to C#/XAML).

I'm wondering which browser engine is used to execute those apps. Is it the engine of the Edge browser? Or IE 11? Or something different?

Knowing the engine would make it easier to check for compatibility of frameworks and Javascript features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, JavaScript/HTML5/CSS3 is native to the Windows Universal Platform.
Here is a very first tutorial :

- [Create a "Hello, world" app (JS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt280216.aspx) *([archive](http://archive.is/mvMZX))*

Microsoft Edge and the Universal Windows Platform share the same core components, mainly Chakra (The JavaScript engine) and EdgeHTML (The HTML/CSS rendering engine). You'll get more details here :

- [Using Chakra for Scripting Applications across Windows 10](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/18/using-chakra-for-scripting-applications-across-windows-10/) *([archive](http://archive.is/h2pSP))*